# how to trigger a MVC application?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

how do you trigger a MVC application.

im only used to use procedural coding. since everything are classes, how do i trigger the first method, where should this method be put, and what should the class holding this starter method be called?

thanks

Comment: Simply put: by issueing Requests against a (Front-)Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too general of a question. The answer will be subjective, because it can be done in many different ways. Your best bet is to look at a simple, lightweight MVC framework, see how they did it, and use that as a guide. I recommend checking out [LightVC](http://www.lightvc.org/).

Generally all requests are routed through an `index.php` file. The request url is inspected to figure out what class file to include. For example, a request to `/users/login` would fire up `Users_Controller`, and then it would execute the `login()` method on the `Users_Controller` class. This is how most frameworks do it, but like I said, you should look at their source to get a better feel.

Answer (score 1):

MVC applications have routers which based on the URL will call the appropriate controller and function inside.

Take a look at the flowchart of CodeIgniter for example -
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Remember an MVC application is like a website, so when the user visits a page in their browser, it will call the methods automatically associated with that page, in the Controller.

Comment: I can see where he's coming from, if you're new to web development it can be a little confusing, especially one as decoupled as MVC